# Using RAM Job Sore in clustered environment quartz

Tags: websphere, quartz-scheduler

I have to develop a scheduler that would run in a clustered environment on Websphere

I do not wish to store the job in the db as the timing for the job is stored in the properties file.

The job has to run once a day and I would not mind if it runs twice on both nodes

will using a RAM job store to schedule work or would it create some unforseen issues

Websphere 7
Quartz 1.8.6

Answer (score 0):

RAM implementation itself can't be enabled to Cluster environment.

WebSphere Application Server has [`Scheduling Service`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.zseries.doc/info/zseries/ae/welc6tech_sch_adm.html). You can easy to use it. It works in Cluster environment perfectly.

You can also use `Asynchronous beans`. [IBM doc.](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/asyncbns/concepts/casb_timemanager.html)

As [IBM article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0609_alcott/0609_alcott.html) said:

```
Packages, such as quartz and the JDK Timer, start unmanaged threads and should be avoided.
```

Comment: answer is useful but not what I was looking for .. Thanks